# Invariant integration on principal bundles

Tags: lie-groups, measure-theory, topological-groups, principal-bundles, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a sufficiently nice topological or Lie group (e.g. compact), and let $H$ be a closed subgroup. This data determines a principal $H$ bundle $G \rightarrow G/H$ defined by the projection $g \mapsto gH$.

In this case, we have Haar measures on $G$ and $G/H$ which allow us to perform invariant integration. I am wondering how this can be generalized to more general principal bundles.

Let $P$ be a principal $H$ bundle with automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut}(P)$. Is it possible to define an $\operatorname{Aut}(P)$-invariant measure on $P$, or otherwise define an invariant integral (e.g. using differential forms) of vector valued functions on P?

More specifically, I am interested in integrating over $P$ functions $f$ in the following space:
$$ M = \{ f : P \rightarrow V \; | \; f(ph) = \rho(h^{-1}) f(p) \}.
$$
Where $(\rho, V)$ is a representation of $H$. (Functions in $M$ are in one to one correspondence with sections of the associated vector bundle $P \times_\rho V$)

The automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut}(P)$ acts on $M$ by $f(p) \mapsto f(a^{-1} p)$ for $a \in \operatorname{Aut}(P)$. If I'm not mistaken, we have for the bundle $G \rightarrow G/H$ that the Haar measure is invariant to this action. Hence my question is whether there is such a thing as "generalized Haar measure" on more general principal bundles.

Comment: First, you need to clarify on which space you want to construct this measure. Next, recall that the group of gauge  transformations is *infinite dimensional*. On which space is this group supposed to act?  There are many possible choices.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added some information to my question: I am interested in integrating vector-valued functions on P, as well as integrating sections of vector bundles associated to $P$, i.e. $P \times_\rho V$ for some representation $\rho$ of $H$. Let me know if you need more information (I'm new to this stuff). Thanks!

Comment: You want to integrate these over what space? On which space is the $Aut(P)$-invariant measure defined?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I've edited the question again. I'm looking for an $\operatorname{Aut}(P)$-invariant measure on $P$ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}$

You should start with a  simple case

$$M=\bR^n,\;\; G=\GL_m(\bR),\;\;P=G\times M. $$

In this case
$$
\Aut(P)=C^\infty\big(\; \bR^n,\;\GL_k(\bR)\;\big).
$$
The action of  gauge transformation $\gamma:\bR^n\to\GL_m(\bR)$ on $P$ is given by
$$
\gamma\cdot(x,g)=(x,\gamma(x)\cdot g).
$$
For $g\in G$ denote by $\gamma_g$ the constant  gausge transformation $\gamma_g(x)=g$, $\forall x\in\bR^n$.

Any  top degree  form $\omega^P$ on $P$     admits a canonical decomposition

$$
\omega^P= \rho(x,g)dV_n\wedge dV_G,
$$ 
where $dV_G$ is  a **left** invariant Haar form on $G$, $dV_n$ denotes the Euclidean volume form on $\bR^n$ and $\rho$ is a function $P\to\bR$.

If $\omega^P$ is $\Aut(P)$ -invariant  then from the equality $\gamma_g^*\omega^P=\omega^P$ we deduce that $\rho(x,g)$ is independent  of $g$.

The exterior derivative  $d^P$ on $P$  decomposes as a sum
$$
d^P= d^M+d^G.
$$
If we write 
$$
dV_G =f(g)\bigwedge_{i,j} dg_{ij},\;\; g=(g_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq m},
$$
then for any $\gamma\in\Aut(P)$ we have
$$
\gamma^*\omega= \rho(x)f(\gamma(x)g) \Bigg(d_M\bigwedge \big(\gamma(x)g\big)_{ij}+ d_G\bigwedge d_G\big(\gamma(x)g\big)_{ij}\;\Bigg)\wedge dV_n
$$
$$
=\rho(x)f(\gamma(x)g)\Bigg(d_G\big(\gamma(x)g\big)_{ij}\;\Bigg)\wedge dV_n
$$
$$
=\omega^P_{x,\gamma(x)g},
$$
where at the last step we  used the left invariance of $dV_G$.

Thus in this case there exist  $\Aut(P)$-invariant volume forms on $P$.
$$
\omega^P\rho(x) dV_n\wedge dV_G.
$$ 
For a general bundle with general structure  group  $G$ the issue of existence of $\Aut(P)$-invariant forms localizes to  the above situation and we conclude that such volume forms exist in general.

**Remark.** The [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) exists on *locally compact* groups.  The group of gauge transformations is infinite dimensional and so it is not locally compact.

Comment: I think you forgot the target of your Haar measure link.  There are concepts of Haar-type measures for more exotic groups than locally compact ones, but they tend also to take more exotic values, and so maybe aren't appropriate here.

Comment: Thank you! I will study your answer. If I understand correctly you consider here the group of automorphisms that fix the base space ("B-automorphisms"). What happens if we include more general ones? E.g. the one given by translation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or left translation on $G$, where $G$ is viewed as a principal $H$ bundle?  I guess an invariant measure still exists then?

Comment: Also, if you have any references to textbooks or papers where this material is covered, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Give me a *concrete* example that interests you and I will attempt to give you a precise answer.

Comment: Let me ask next, once you have such an invariant measure what would you use it for?